# GCP Python - Delete Project Labels

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to delete labels from projects, by using the UpdateProjectRequest.

It says that it needs an 'update_mask', but I do not know how to created this mask. It is a google.protobuf.field_mask_pb2.FieldMask

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.types.UpdateProjectRequest

What i have tried is:

```py
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

def sample_update_project(project_id):
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()

    
    update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=["labels.newkey:None"])
    resourcemanager_v3.Project=f"projects/{project_id}"
    
    operation = client.update_project(update_mask=update_mask)
    
    
    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result()
    
    
    print(response)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, when you want to delete all labels, it requires an update mask for the labels field.
Reviewing this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsClient_update_project), please note that if a request is provided, this should not be set. Also, you will find a code example that might help you.

Additionally, you should import `filed_mask_pb2` if you will [update data with a FieldMask](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/field-mask#detect-intent-tts-python) use as follows:

```
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2
```

Having the main question in mind, one of two methods can be used to [remove a label](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/labeling-resources#removing_a_label):

Use the read-modify-write pattern to completely remove the label, which removes both the key and the value. To do this, perform these steps:

- Use the resource's get() function to read the current labels.
- Use a text editor or programmatically change the returned labels to
  add or remove any necessary keys and their values.
- Call the patch() function on the resource to write the changed
  labels.

To keep the key and remove the value, set the value to `null`, but reviewing your code, you are currently using `None`.

Also, consider the following documentation:[Creating and managing labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#update-labels) and [Method: projects.patch](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/patch?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2F668043786777%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22labels%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D)

**UPDATE**

Working again with your main question, here is a code that it was already tested to delete labels as you requested:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery 

def sample_update_project_old(project_id): 
    manager = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1') 
    request = manager.projects().get(projectId=project_id) 
    project = request.execute() 
    del project['labels']['key'] # replace 'key' with your actual key value 
    request = manager.projects().update(projectId=project_id, body=project) 
    project = request.execute() 

sample_update_project_old("your-project-id")
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you very much. 
I had to modify it a bit, but it's working:
https://gist.github.com/tundragon/6c4523f89bde8a96ad119bc995250859


I will open some beers to your health.